# How to create a list with an attribute taken from objects of a list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let's assume there is a class `Person` with attributes `name` and `age` and there is a list `persons` with n person objects. Is there a more efficient way of creating an age list from the list `persons` other than this:

```kotlin
val age_list= ArrayList<Int>()
for(person in persons){
    age_list.add(person.getAge())
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simply map one list to another.

```
val ageList = persons.map { it.age }
```

You could also replace the explicit lambda with a function reference.

```
val ageList = persons.map(Person::age)
```

If you need to have an `ArrayList<Int>` as result, you can use the `mapTo` function to map into an `ArrayList<Int>` instead of the default `List<Int>`.

```
val ageList = persons.mapTo(arrayListOf()) { it.age }
```

---

This assumes you have a dataset along the lines of:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

val persons = listOf(
    Person("Pete", 31),
    Person("Luna", 19),
    Person("Hendrick", 45),
)
```

Comment: _If you need to have an `ArrayList<Int>` as result, you can call `toTypedArray()`_ - `List#toTypedArray` converts `List<T>` to `Array<T>` not `ArrayList<T>`. To properly create `ArrayList<T>` from `List<T>` you should just use the `ArrayList` constructor: `val arrayList = ArrayList(list)`

Comment: Oops, you're completely right @jsamol, Thanks. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: To create an `ArrayList`, call `persons.mapTo(destination) { it.age }`. This avoids creating a list twice.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Adjusted the code sample, thanks.